# jemalloc and other errors making redis on centos 6.4

Tags: centos, make

I am setting up a new, dedicated, centos 6.4 system with redis. I have installed redis many times, but have never hit this issue (and have never been on centos 6.4 before).

```
cd redis-2.6.16
sudo make install
```

error:

```
MAKE jemalloc
cd jemalloc && ./configure --with-lg-quantum=3 --with-jemalloc-prefix=je_ --enable-cc-silence CFLAGS="-std=gnu99 -Wall -pipe -g3 -O3 -funroll-loops " LDFLAGS=""
/bin/sh: ./configure: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [jemalloc] Error 126
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/redis32/redis-3.2.6/deps'
make[1]: [persist-settings] Error 2 (ignored)


    sh: ./mkreleasehdr.sh: Permission denied
and later:
    zmalloc.h:50:31: error: jemalloc/jemalloc.h: No such file or directory
    zmalloc.h:55:2: error: #error "Newer version of jemalloc required"
```

When I try to build jemalloc directly (from the /src area of the redis tarball), other errors include:

```
cd src && make jemalloc
sh: ./mkreleasehdr.sh: Permission denied
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/rediswork/redis-2.6.16/src'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `jemalloc'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/rediswork/redis-2.6.16/src'
make: *** [jemalloc] Error 2
```

I also tried redis 2.6.7 and have the same issue.

I have dug all over and can find no path forward.

Comment: http://blog.gbinghan.com/2012/05/installing-redis-jemallocjemalloch-no.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On this system `/tmp` was mounted `noexec`.

Redis runs a number of shell scripts from `/tmp` during its install, so the solution is to remount `/tmp` without the `noexec` flag. This does this temporarily:

```
mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

I should add that this solution applies to all redis 2.x and 3.x versions (4.x is os far unknown to me)

Comment: How in hell does this resolve the error you posted in the question?!

Comment: Hey, I do not know. But I know that a tech I am working with suggested it, and it did solve. I have installed/built redis several times, and have never hit this issue before.

Comment: @MichaelHampton some of the errors are "Access denied" errors during make. Error posted is the first error (I believe, the make output is loooong).

Comment: You should have posted the complete output. This question and answer make absolutely no sense together.

Comment: Could it be that the system in question s 32bit? @MichaelHampton  In that case , try make 32bit.

Comment: @RomanM No, it is not a 32 bit question. The problem is that I was trying to build it in a dir struct where only had read access. The problem under the problem is that the makefile assumes write access, and does not give a clear error.

Comment: @MichaelHampton fwiw, I just hit the issue again, on a fresh centos 6.7 system. I enhanced the OP above to show the earlier access denied error, which is resolved by the remount command above. The root issue, I believe, is that I am using a subdir of /tmp as my workdir, which appears to be a bad practice that I will change. I hope this addresses your concern from 3 yrs ago.

Comment: Yes, now the question makes sense with the answer.

Answer (score 115):

I ran into the same issue on centos 6.4 and had to run the following commands:

```
cd deps
make hiredis jemalloc linenoise lua geohash-int
cd ..
make install
```

I am not sure why the deps where not built, I thought they were in the past. However, this got me up and running with the version of redis that I needed.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on a centos 6.4 instance on EC2.

Comment: `make hiredis` gave error for me, but the rest worked (on EC2 machine)

Comment: Update: this worked: `unset ARCH; make  hiredis`. From https://github.com/redis/hiredis-rb/issues/2

Comment: I had to add `geohash-int` to the make target as well (i.e.  `make hiredis jemalloc linenoise lua geohash-int`) for Amazon Linux

Comment: Worked for me on centos 7.

Comment: Worked like a charm in ubuntu  16.04 EC2 instance as well

Comment: Same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 and this fix worked for me too

Comment: worked on Amazon AmI as well

Comment: @Clemorphy's solution below points out that this may be caused by leftover files from a previously failed `make` command - his answer is clean and elegant, check it out.

Comment: This plus previously installing build essentials (sudo apt-get install build-essential) worked on ubuntu 20.04 as well

Answer (score 83):

I had the same errors after a first failure caused by a missing package (gcc).
So after installing gcc, another `make` attempt gave these errors :

```
zmalloc.h:50:31: error: jemalloc/jemalloc.h: No such file or directory
zmalloc.h:55:2: error: #error "Newer version of jemalloc required"
```

These errors were caused by some files left here after the failure of the first `make` command.
Apparently I had to clean these files, with the command :

```
make distclean
```

And then `make` again, and it worked.

Source : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/-guYpX2OCSk

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. I had the same scenario: ran `make` before installing `build-essential` and `tcl8.5`.

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: This is very much the right answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try installing the package it asked for?

```
yum install jemalloc-devel
```

This can be found in the EPEL repository, which you should have already added to your CentOS system.

Come to think of it, `redis` is also in EPEL...

Comment: Yes, I did try that.... didn't help.... solution is above.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this for Redis 3.0.2 on RHEL-6.6 as follows:

From the Redis install directory,

1. Run `./deps/update-jemalloc.sh 3.6.0` (where 3.6.0 is the latest version of jemalloc that works with Redis 3.0.2 as of this writing)
2. Run `make distclean && make`

Answer (score 1):

Its happen due to dirty make file so before run

```
$ sudo make
```

run this:

```
$ make distclean
```

sure it'll solve all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

same problem that I met when make redis-3.0.0 on CentOS-6.6x86, try this to make it.

```
make MALLOC=libc
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after I killed the build part-way through and tried to make it again. `make clean` did not help so I nuked the directory and started over, and it compiled fine.

Answer (score 0):

At first, after extracting files from `redis.<version>.tar.gz` make failed because there was no gcc installed :

```
gcc: Command not found
```

So I installed gcc:

```
sudo yum install gcc-c++
```

Then I ran the make again ,I received :

```
zmalloc.h:50:31: error: jemalloc/jemalloc.h: No such file or directory
zmalloc.h:55:2: error: #error "Newer version of jemalloc required"
```

I removed the redis extraced folder and re-extracted it from `redis.<version>.tar.gz` .Since gcc is installed this time , everything went successfully when I run `make`.
I ran from inside redis extracted directory :

```
sudo make install
```